# Kotlin prepend element

Tags: list, insert, kotlin, prepend, cons

I am searching for Kotlin alternative to:
    `(cons 1 '(2 3))` in lisp or
    `1 : [2, 3]` in haskell or
    `1 :: List(2, 3)` in scala,
**(which all result in sth like [1, 2, 3])**
so I can prepend an element to a `List<T>` (or any other list you can offer).

It will also be fine if one could provide O(1) `head` and `tail` Kotlin alternatives (I've found just `first()`)

Comment: Are lists linked? It can be an expensive operation to prepend if the structure isn't made for it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate They should be [Kotlin Standart Library](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html).

Comment: @Columpio "They should be [linked lists]" - why do you think so? Kotlin's stdlib uses linked lists very rarely. The link you provided has no info on the issue.

Comment: check this for the mutable list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66668823/10784151

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any class which implements `Deque` will suitable for you, for example `LinkedList`:

```
val linkedList = LinkedList(listOf(2, 3))
linkedList.push(1)
println(linkedList) // [1, 2, 3]
```

Creating lists throught constructor `LinkedList(listOf(2, 3))` in many places can be annoying, so feel free to write factory method:

```
fun <T> linkedListOf(vararg elements: T): LinkedList<T> {
    return LinkedList<T>(elements.toList())
}

// Usage:
val list = linkedListOf(2, 3)
list.push(1)
println(list) // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Is there any method to actually _return_ new List?
`push` will change the list, I don't want that

Comment: @Columpio For now you have to use third-party collection library to get efficient immutable collections

Answer (score 36):

I think the easiest would be to write:

```
var list = listOf(2,3)
println(list) // [2, 3]
list = listOf(1) + list
println(list) // [1, 2, 3]
```

There is no specific `tail` implementation, but you can call .drop(1) to get the same. You can make this `head\tail` more generic by writing these extension properties:

```
val <T> List<T>.tail: List<T>
  get() = drop(1)

val <T> List<T>.head: T
  get() = first()
```

Then:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val head = list.head
val tail = list.tail
```

Some more info: [Kotlin List tail function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808022/kotlin-list-tail-function)

Comment: Beware that performance would suffer as Kotlin lists are not optimized for such operations unlike Scala ones.

Answer (score 12):

Simple, just wrap the element to prepend in a `List` and then use the `+` operator (or `List.plus()`) to concatenate the two `Lists`:

```
val list1 = listOf(2, 3)        // [2, 3]
val list2 = listOf(1) + list1   // [1, 2, 3]
```

For your second question, in Kotlin 1.2 there are:

```
List.first()
List.last()
```

Both are O(1)

Answer (score 6):

This could be done easily with extension functions as below

### Prepending element

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.prepend(element: T) {
    add(0, element)
}
```

### Prepending list

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.prependAll(elements: List<T>) {
    addAll(0, elements)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inserts an element into the list at the specified index.

```
abstract fun add(index: Int, element: E)
```

Thus answer is

```
list.add(0,element)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do that often in your code for some reason, consider adding an extension operator method such as:

```
operator fun <T> T.plus(tail: List<T>): List<T> {
    val list = ArrayList<T>(1 + tail.size)

    list.add(this)
    list.addAll(tail)

    return list
}
```

Then your code could work Scala-like: `1 + listOf(2, 3)`

Another way to achieve the same behaviour, shorter but sacrifices some memory:

```
operator fun <T> T.plus(tail: List<T>): List<T> {
    return mutableListOf(this).apply {
        addAll(tail)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really nice and what I was expecting Kotlin to have since I also know Scala. It seems like a very natural way to write code being able to append / prepend a single item to a collection.

Answer (score 0):

To be as close to Lisp as possible consider using immutable linked list.

You can use [pcollections](https://github.com/hrldcpr/pcollections)

```
val list = ConsPStack.from(listOf(2, 3))
val newList = list + 1
println(list)  // [2, 3]
println(newList) // [1, 2, 3]
```

Head:

```
list.first() // 1
list[0] // 1
```

(unfortunately this thing needs one allocation)

Tail:

```
list - 0 // [2, 3]
list.subList(1) // [2, 3]
```

Looks rather ugly.

Hopefully we'll get better API when [kotlinx.collections.immutable](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable) will be ready. It's an effort to create standard Kotlin immutable collections (not just read-only ones that we currently have). As of now this project is still at very early stage (I was unable to find structure that supports efficient prepend/head/tail there)

Answer (score -5):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, so please try one of the following.

Mutating list:

```
val list = mutableListOf(3, 2)
list.add(1)
```

Copping an immutable list:

```
var list = listOf(3, 2)
list = list + 1
```

Comment: **prepend** an element, not append

Comment: Ya, this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: In Haskell the most efficient operation is prepending, so that is what people do. In Kotlin appending is more efficient in most cases, that's why it is much more common.

Comment: I don't see a big philosophical difference between prepending and appending. If you use a list as a stack (as you do in Haskell), then you get the same result regardless of the end of the list you use. The order changes, but who cares.