# What is the best way to add an element to the beginning of a list in Kotlin

Tags: list, arraylist, kotlin

If I have a list like this one

```
 var foo = mutableListOf("John", "Wayne")
```

and if I want to add an element on top of the list, so far I am thinking of two options.

First: `foo.add(0, "Twyla")`

Second: `foo = (mutableListOf("Twyla") + foo).toMutableList()`

I am not how the above two options fare in terms of performance but what is a recommended way in general?

Comment: You could use a queue implementation, for example a `LinkedList`?

Comment: Yes, I can, but let's say for a different reason I am avoiding using LinkedList.

Comment: Afaik, there's no API support in Kotlin (at least on v1.3) like in Scala which allows you to prepend an element to a List.

Comment: If you want to modify the existing List, then `add(0, )` is probably the best way.  Its performance will depend on the List implementation,  but if it's one that allows efficient insertion (such as LinkedList), then `add()` will probably do that.  (If performance is really important, make sure you're using a LinkedList, or rearrange the code so you only need to add at the _end_ of the list.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two options are not quite the same: the first one just inserts an item into the beginning of the *existing* mutable list, and the second creates a new list and then converts it into another one new mutable list.

I think if you're fine with mutating the existing list, you should prefer the first option because it requires way less memory than the second one.

Answer (score 9):

You can use add(index, value) method.

```
fun main() {    
    val list1: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(2,3,4)
    println(list1.toString())

    list1.add(0, 1)
    println(list1.toString()) 
}

Output: 
  [2, 3, 4]
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```